# ¿cómo puedo actualizar los datos de un objeto, con otro objeto en javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, angular9

Tengo el siguiente objeto que compone un datagrid en angular

```
dataGrid = [{
AgrupadorId: "1"
CodigoId: "1"
CompartidoId: "Si"
DescripcionId: "1"
ID: "efc82e56-6c8b-6365-ba20-6db419e1c5a9"
LargoId: "1"
OrdenId: "1"
TablaNumeroId: "1"
TipoDatoId: "N - Número con decimales"
VisibleId: "Si"
},
{
AgrupadorId: "2"
CodigoId: "2"
CompartidoId: "Si"
DescripcionId: "2"
ID: "e4077e5e-8967-5c1a-4183-e5fc40325ffb"
LargoId: "2"
OrdenId: "2"
TablaNumeroId: "2"
TipoDatoId: "N - Número con decimales"
VisibleId: "Si"
},
{
AgrupadorId: "3"
CodigoId: "3"
CompartidoId: "No"
DescripcionId: "3"
ID: "63b67583-9e97-5df5-2319-96542d21a8b2"
LargoId: "3"
OrdenId: "3"
TablaNumeroId: "3"
TipoDatoId: "N - Número con decimales"
VisibleId: "No"
}]
```

Al actualizar un item de dicho dataGrid, me retorna dos items newData y oldData, donde newData únicamente tiene los valores que se actualizaron

```
oldData = {
AgrupadorId: "2"
CodigoId: "2"
CompartidoId: "Si"
DescripcionId: "2"
ID: "e4077e5e-8967-5c1a-4183-e5fc40325ffb"
LargoId: "2"
OrdenId: "2"
TablaNumeroId: "2"
TipoDatoId: "N - Número con decimales"
VisibleId: "Si"
}
newData = {
AgrupadorId: "____2"
DescripcionId: "descripción 2"
}
```

Necesito saber como puedo actualizar el objeto dataGrid teniendo en cuenta el ID de oldData y los valores de newData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre resolver así:

```
 Object.keys(data).forEach(k => {
  Object.keys(newData).forEach(z => {
   if (k === z) {                    
    x[k] = newData[z];
   }
  });
 });
```

De esta forma se modifican en el objeto los valores que fueron cambiados.

Answer (score 0):

*Debes hacer el cambio manual, es decir tienes un objetos que llamas oldData donde este tiene 10 campos en total, pero en el newData solo están los que modificas. la forma sería de la siguiente manera:*

```js
// Objeto inicial
data = {
  AgrupadorId: "2"
  CodigoId: "2"
  CompartidoId: "Si"
  DescripcionId: "2"
  ID: "e4077e5e-8967-5c1a-4183-e5fc40325ffb"
  LargoId: "2"
  OrdenId: "2"
  TablaNumeroId: "2"
  TipoDatoId: "N - Número con decimales"
  VisibleId: "Si"
}

// objeto con los campos a modificar
editData = {
  AgrupadorId: "____2"
  DescripcionId: "descripción 2"
}

// De esta manera cambias los valores de la data inicial
data.AgrupadorId = editData.AgrupadorId;
data.DescripcionId = editData.DescripcionId;
```

*De esta manera conservas toda la info de tu objeto **data** o **oldData** como lo llamaste.*

*Espero te sirva*

Comment: el tema esta en que en newData no siempre se modifican los mismo campos, puede ser cualquiera de los que tenga el objeto, no tengo forma de saber cual será modificado.